# Cancel NSTimer in NSRunLoop

Tags: ios, nstimer, nsrunloop

I'm currently doing this:

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:timeUntilAction target:self selector:@selector(actionToPerform) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

But I would like to be able to invalidate that timer. Calling invalidate doesn't seem to do anything and I don't know what else to try, since I can't remove the timer from the `NSRunLoop` from any instance methods that I can see for `NSTimer` or `NSRunLoop`.

How should I set a method (actionToPerform) up to fire after a certain delay (timeUntilAction), but still have the ability to cancel the action, given certain user interaction. The user should also be able to reinitiate the timer before the initial timer (one that was cancelled) was scheduled to go off.

Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Just for kicks, add it to `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` instead of `NSRunLoopCommonModes`.  The second one can cause unanticipated behavior in my experience (though, checking the docs, I understand why now).  `invalidate` definitely will remove it from the run loop, and if it doesn't then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @borrrden Oh goodness. You were right. I screwed up in an if statement. Now everyone can downvote me for not fully testing my code! I was just sure that I hadn't screwed up, but I put it in one block too far. I just needed some coffee. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone close this question? Or delete it?

Comment: Can you not delete it yourself?  I don't have an option to.

Comment: Not with answers. A moderator will have to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(actionToPerform) withObject:nil afterDelay:timeUntilAction]

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(actionToPerform) object:nil]
```

Comment: Cool. The timer works, but this also should work, if you included the inRunLoop part.

Answer (score 1):

you can Cancel NSTimer in NSRunLoop.
Even if you don't find API within NSTimer nor NSRunloop, you can try CFRunLoop.
according to Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopRemoveTimer), see how:

First,

`CFRunLoopRef *cfrl = [NSRunLoop getCFRunLoop];`

Then,

CFRunLoopAddTimer

```
void CFRunLoopAddTimer ( CFRunLoopRef rl, CFRunLoopTimerRef timer, CFStringRef mode );
```

CFRunLoopRemoveTimer

```
void CFRunLoopRemoveTimer ( CFRunLoopRef rl, CFRunLoopTimerRef timer, CFStringRef mode );
```

P.S. especially about

`- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector
             withObject:(id)anArgument
             afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay`

see Apple doc. for [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:)

> **Special Considerations**
>
> This method registers with the runloop of its current context, and depends on that runloop being run on a regular basis to perform correctly. One common context where you might call this method and end up registering with a runloop that is not automatically run on a regular basis is when being invoked by a dispatch queue. If you need this type of functionality when running on a dispatch queue, you should use`dispatch_after` and related methods to get the behavior you want.

Also, you can use **MSWeakTimer** on GitHub.